# Making the textSize adjust to the EditText

Tags: android, layout, text, android-linearlayout

I have this code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="@string/tip_value" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="@string/tip_value" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="@string/tip_value" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image: outcome of code above]

How can I make textSize adjusting to the height of the EditText ?

I mean to uppercase letters span whole height of the edit text (which could be different sizes because of linearLayout)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the height of each view inside your `listView` and define the text size for that specific view. For this you will have to use custom adapter to show the `array` or `arrayList` (or `cursor`...) in the `listView`. In your custom adapter under `getView()` you can do `convertView.getHeight()` to get the exact height of the specific view in pixels, and then set the `textView` size for that view in `getView()`. Should be something similar to this:
(I haven't checked this code i'm writing it for you as example)

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    .
    .
    .
    View line = convertView;
    float size = line.getHeight();
    TextView text = findViewById...
    text.setTextSize(size-20);
    return line;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is like this.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="please Enter" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="please Enter" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="please Enter" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: But I want to make them "weight". To span whole space.. In your example I do need anyway set textSize which wouldn't be adjusting to the screen.